# Weird post back behavior on ASP.NET web form while refreshing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, refresh, postback

In an ASP.NET web form, I have two button controls and I have come across a weird scenario.
I have btnOpenAddRoleModal and btn2. when I click on btnOpenAddRoleModal, btnAddGlobalRoles becomes visible and then I click on btnAddGlobalRoles which performs some function.

Now when I press F5 to refresh the page, and because ASP.NET post-backs the page again on refresh, it does the post back as usual.

My problem is that it runs the click event handler of btnOpenAddRoleModal instead of btnAddGlobalRoles whereas the last button I clicked was btnAddGlobalRoles.

Anyone knows why this could be a case?

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MainTheme.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GlobalRoles.aspx.cs" Inherits="OPT.GlobalRoles" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <header style="overflow: auto;">
        <h1 class="zs-left">Global Roles</h1>
        <div class="zs-right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnOpenAddRoleModal" runat="server" Text="Add User" CssClass="zs-button zs-button-action" OnClick="btnOpenAddRoleModal_Click" OnClientClick="return IncreasePostBackControlValue();" />
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="page-2cols" style="position: relative;">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h2 class="zs-inner-title">Roles</h2>
                <p class="zs-search-button">
                    <span class="zs-input-icon zs-icon-search">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSearchText" runat="server" Text="Search Roles " Style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" runat="server" CssClass="zs-input" placehoder="Enter key words to search" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtSearchText_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNoResultsMessage" runat="server" Text="No results found" Visible="false"></asp:Label></p>
                <p>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvGlobalRoles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="gvGlobalRoles_RowDeleting" CssClass="zs-data-table">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Sr. No." />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Employee Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleName" HeaderText="Role" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <span class="zs-icon zs-icon-delete"></span>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </p>

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" CssClass="zs-overlay" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" Visible="false" CssClass="zs-modal" Style="display: inline-block; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" runat="server">
                    <header>
                        <span><% =ModalTitle %></span>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCloseModal" runat="server" CssClass="zs-icon zs-icon-close zs-icon-large" OnClick="lbCloseModal_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </header>
                    <section>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblModalMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDeleteListItem" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            You have selected to delete a role. Press OK to continue or Cancel to abort.
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEditListItem" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeToAdd" runat="server" Text="Employee Email"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeToAdd" runat="server" CssClass="zs-input"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRoleToAdd" runat="server" Text="Role"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoleToAdd" runat="server" CssClass="zs-input"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </p>
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </section>
                    <footer>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancelModal" runat="server" OnClick="lbCancelModal_Click">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddGlobalRoles" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="zs-button zs-button-action" OnClick="btnAddGlobalRoles_Click" OnClientClick="return IncreasePostBackControlValue();" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteGlobalRole" runat="server" CssClass="zs-button zs-button-action" Text="OK" OnClick="btnDeleteGlobalRole_Click" OnClientClick="return IncreasePostBackControlValue();" Visible="false" />
                    </footer>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPostBackControl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                <script>
                    //$(document).on("click", "button,input[type='submit'],input[type='button']", function () {
                    //    $("#hfPostBackControl").val($("#hfPostBackControl").val() == "" ? 1 : Number($("#hfPostBackControl").val()) + 1);
                    //});

                    function IncreasePostBackControlValue() {
                        $("#hfPostBackControl").val($("#hfPostBackControl").val() == "" ? 1 : Number($("#hfPostBackControl").val()) + 1);
                        return true;
                    }
                </script>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using OPT.Models;

namespace OPT
{
    public partial class GlobalRoles : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        BAL bal = new BAL();
        string message = "";
        int messageStateID;
        DataTable dtRoles;
        DataTable dtGlobalEmployeeRoles;
        GlobalRole globalRoleToDelete;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadRoleDropDown();
                LoadGlobalRolesFromDatabase();
                Session["sPostBackValue"] = 0;
            }

            Generic.HideControls(AllMessageControls);
        }

        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CurrentPage"] = ePage.GlobalRoles;
        }

        protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Pages.ShowGlobalRoles())
            {
                Generic.RediretToMesagePage("Unauthorized user");
            }

            if (gvGlobalRoles.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvGlobalRoles.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                lblNoResultsMessage.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblNoResultsMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        void LoadGlobalRolesFromDatabase()
        {
            dtGlobalEmployeeRoles = bal.GetGlobalEmployeeRoles(txtSearchText.Text, ref message, ref messageStateID);
            Session["GlobalEmployeeRoles"] = dtGlobalEmployeeRoles;
            gvGlobalRoles.DataSource = Session["GlobalEmployeeRoles"] as DataTable;
            gvGlobalRoles.DataBind();
        }

        void LoadRoleDropDown()
        {
            dtRoles = bal.GetGlobalRoles(ref message, ref messageStateID);
            Generic.PopulateDataTableInDropDown(ddlRoleToAdd, dtRoles, "ID", "Name", "Please select");
        }

        protected void gvGlobalRoles_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            globalRoleToDelete = new GlobalRole();

            dtGlobalEmployeeRoles = Session["GlobalEmployeeRoles"] as DataTable;
            globalRoleToDelete.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dtGlobalEmployeeRoles.Rows[rowIndex]["ID"].ToString());

            Session["CurrentGlobalRole"] = globalRoleToDelete;

            ModalTitle = "Delete Role";
            Generic.ShowControls(modalDeleteControls);
        }

        protected void btnAddGlobalRoles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Generic.IsRefresh(hfPostBackControl)) { return; }

            Employee employee = new Employee();
            Role role = new Role();

            employee.EmailID = txtEmployeeToAdd.Text;
            role.ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoleToAdd.SelectedValue);

            bal.CreateGlobalEmployeeRole(employee, role, ref message, ref messageStateID);
            if (messageStateID == 1)
            {
                Generic.HideControls(modalAllControls);
                Generic.ShowMessage(lblMessage, message, messageStateID);
            }
            else
            {
                ModalTitle = eModalTitle.EditProject;
                Generic.ShowMessage(lblModalMessage, message, messageStateID);
            }
            LoadGlobalRolesFromDatabase();
        }

        protected void btnDeleteGlobalRole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Generic.IsRefresh(hfPostBackControl)) { return; }

            globalRoleToDelete = Session["CurrentGlobalRole"] as GlobalRole;
            bal.DeleteGlobalEmployeeRole(globalRoleToDelete, ref message, ref messageStateID);
            if (messageStateID == 1)
            {
                Generic.HideControls(modalAllControls);
                Generic.ShowMessage(lblMessage, message, messageStateID);
            }
            else
            {
                ModalTitle = eModalTitle.EditProject;
                Generic.ShowMessage(lblModalMessage, message, messageStateID);
            }
            LoadGlobalRolesFromDatabase();
            Generic.HideControls(modalDeleteControls);
        }

        protected void lbCloseModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Generic.HideControls(modalAllControls);
        }


        protected void lbCancelModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Generic.HideControls(modalAllControls);
        }

        protected void btnOpenAddRoleModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Generic.IsRefresh(hfPostBackControl)) { return; }

            ModalTitle = "Add Role";
            Generic.ClearControlValuesInContainer(pnlAddEditListItem);
            Generic.ShowControls(modalAddControls);
        }

        protected void txtSearchText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadGlobalRolesFromDatabase();
        }
        private string _ModalTitle;

        public string ModalTitle
        {
            get { return _ModalTitle; }
            set { _ModalTitle = value; }
        }

        protected List<Control> modalAllControls
        {
            get
            {
                List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
                controls.AddRange(modalGenericControls);
                controls.AddRange(modalAddControls);
                controls.AddRange(modalDeleteControls);

                return controls;
            }
        }

        protected List<Control> modalGenericControls
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Control>{
                    pnlOverlay as Control,
                    pnlModal as Control
                };
            }
        }

        protected List<Control> modalDeleteControls
        {
            get
            {
                List<Control> controls = new List<Control>{
                    pnlDeleteListItem as Control,
                    btnDeleteGlobalRole as Control
                };

                controls.AddRange(this.modalGenericControls);
                return controls;
            }
        }

        protected List<Control> modalAddControls
        {
            get
            {
                List<Control> controls = new List<Control>{
                    pnlAddEditListItem as Control,
                    btnAddGlobalRoles as Control
                };
                controls.AddRange(this.modalGenericControls);

                return controls;
            }
        }

        protected List<Control> AllMessageControls
        {
            get
            {
                List<Control> messageControls = new List<Control>{
                    lblMessage as Control,
                    lblModalMessage as Control
                };

                return messageControls;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Few supporting methods here

```
    public static bool IsRefresh(HiddenField hfPostBackControl)
    {
        int sPostBackValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["sPostBackValue"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["sPostBackValue"]);
        int hPostBackValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hfPostBackControl.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfPostBackControl.Value);

        HttpContext.Current.Session["sPostBackValue"] = hPostBackValue;

        return sPostBackValue == hPostBackValue;            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be used for displaying pop ups after any action. One needs to pass the controls as parameter that need to shown on any event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controls">List of controls that need to be displyed as pop-up</param>
    public static void ShowControls(List<Control> controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            c.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be used for hiding pop ups being displayed. One needs to pass the controls as parameter that need to hidden on any event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controls">List of controls that need to be hidden</param>
    public static void HideControls(List<Control> controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowMessage(Label lblMessage, string message, int messageStateID)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = message;
        lblMessage.CssClass = messageStateID == 1 ? "zs-message zs-success" : "zs-message zs-error";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: please post the code, is impossible to know without reading it

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code

Comment: what I can see at the moment is that you have added:

List<Control> controls = new List<Control>{
                    pnlAddEditListItem as Control,
                    btnAddGlobalRoles as Control
                };

the btnAddGlobalRoles as Control, but the btnOpenAddRoleModal has no Control there. I guess it is for the HideControls method. Maybe the reason is that, when you reload, the button is hidden and, therefore, the last "active" action you made was the btnOpenAddRoleModal. How about you try without hiding them?

Comment: @FedericoJoséSorenson: Thanks for you response. I have tried this already with no success. :(